# fabricjs object / canvas fire an event manually

Tags: fabricjs

i want to manually trigger **select object on the canvas event ** - the same event that fires when a mouse click was made within an object area, and the object become selected - the controls become visible.

so in other words, i want to show controls for a specified object on the canvas MANUALLY, without user/mouse interaction. any help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

solution was found in the docs.

if someone looking for the answer -

```
fabric.Canvas.setActiveObject(fabric.Object) ...
```

how the solution was found:
i understood that the wrong thinking was to look after the event that precedes the 'object:selected', but there is no such event !!! so i realized that all what i had to do is just look in the code for `'object:selected'` and that's how i found which method fires it ... also it is well documented here, in [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Canvas.html) .

suggestion: would be great to note about it in the articles - next to `getActiveObject / Group` . currently it appears only here - http://fabricjs.com/customization/

anyway, cangax and others participators - like very much your work ! 
thanks